# Type trait for strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11, traits

Is there an existing (in the standard library or in Boost) type trait to test whether a type could represent a string?

I stumbled upon an issue when using Boost.Fusion:

```
auto number = fusion::make_vector( 1, "one" );
auto numberName = fusion::filter< char const * >( number );

assert( numberName == fusion::make_vector( "one" ) ); // fails
```

I hoped `filter` would retain "one", but it failed because "one" is not decayed to a pointer (`make_vector` takes its arguments by reference, so the type is `const char (&)[4]`). Consequently, I need a trait that would allow me to write something like this:

```
auto numberName = fusion::filter_if< is_string< mpl::_ > >( number );
```

I am aware that a `char const *` and a `const char[N]` are not necessarily null-terminated strings, but it would still be handy to be able to detect them uniformly. The trait could also possibly return `true` for `std::string` and the likes.

Does such a trait exist or will I have to write my own?

Comment: What about `static_cast<const char *>("one")`? Or a general template that takes arrays and casts them to pointers?

Comment: @KerrekSB: encapsulating every string literal in a function call seems like a real burden, but a function template could be used by the trait to test if the type can be converted to a char pointer...

Comment: Just fyi, you're missing a closing karen in the assert().

Comment: I just realized, if `is_string<std::string>::value` is true, then your conversion to `const char*` won't work, will it?  (did they add an explicit conversion in C++11?)

Comment: @MooingDuck: no, the conversion would not work, but the trait could easily be specialized for `std::string`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I gave a shot at implementing such a trait, but I am not sure it is really robust. Any input will be appreciated.

```
template <typename T>
struct is_string
    : public mpl::or_< // is "or_" included in the C++11 library?
        std::is_same<       char *, typename std::decay< T >::type >,
        std::is_same< const char *, typename std::decay< T >::type >
     > {};

assert ( ! is_string< int >::value );

assert (   is_string< char       *       >::value );
assert (   is_string< char const *       >::value );
assert (   is_string< char       * const >::value );
assert (   is_string< char const * const >::value );

assert (   is_string< char       (&)[5] >::value );
assert (   is_string< char const (&)[5] >::value );

// We could add specializations for string classes, e.g.
template <>
struct is_string<std::string> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: `or_` is not included in 11, no.  The equivalent would, I believe, be `std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<...>::value || std::is_same<...>::value>`.

Comment: `or` is included in the C++17 library. see [std::disjunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) and notice that is **short-circuiting** trait.

Answer (score 9):

This should work in C++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
 
template<typename T>
struct is_string
        : public std::disjunction<
                std::is_same<char *, std::decay_t<T>>,
                std::is_same<const char *, std::decay_t<T>>,
                std::is_same<std::string, std::decay_t<T>>
        > {
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::string str = "i am a string";
    std::cout << is_string<decltype(str)>::value << std::endl; // "true"
    std::cout << is_string<decltype("i am a string literal")>::value << std::endl; // "true"
}
```

Comment: You don't need `typename` on `decay_t`, the `_t` already handles that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Looks like an editor removed `::type` but forgot to remove `typename` as well. Should be fixed now I think.