# templated function which accepts only string or arithmetic

Tags: c++, templates, boost, type-traits

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
template<class Type>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::mpl::or_<
boost::is_arithmetic<Type>,
is_string<Type> > >::type
get(const std::string &argPath, const Type &argDefault) {
    bool caught = false;
    std::stringstream ss;
    Type value;

    try {
        value = ptree_.get<Type>(argPath);
    } catch(ptree_bad_path &e) {
        caught = true;
    }

    if(caught)
        value = argDefault;

    ss << value;
    parameters_.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(argPath, ss.str()));
    return value;
}
```

I used the following is_string type trait: [Type trait for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097534/type-trait-for-strings)

My goal is to restrict my `Type` to string or arithmetic type so that I can push it to my `stringstream`.

So this builds, but when I try to use it, it returns the following errors:

> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
>
> In member function ‘typename
>   boost::enable_if,
>   is_string, mpl_::bool_, mpl_::bool_,
>   mpl_::bool_ >, void>::type FooClass::get(const std::string&,
>   const Type&) [with Type = uint8_t]’
>
> error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'

Here is how I try to use it:

```
FooClass f;
item_value = f.get("tag1.tag2.item", DEFAULT_ITEM_VALUE);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html, `enable_if` has a second parameter that defaults to void:

```
template <bool B, class T = void>
struct enable_if_c {
  typedef T type;
};
```

Seems to me you need to include the return type in your enable_if. (It is defaulting to void now.)

```
template<class Type>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::mpl::or_<
    boost::is_arithmetic<Type>,
    is_string<Type> >,
Type >::type
get(const std::string &argPath, const Type &argDefault);
```

Comment: You are right, it now works as expected! Thanks a lot, you made my day!