# Concept for string-like object

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is there a concept for a string-like object in standard library?
What I mean is something like

```
template<typename T>
concept StringLike = requires(T x) {
   /* is same as const char*, char*, std::string etc */
}
```

There is a question about handmade
[Type trait for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097534/type-trait-for-strings). But I cannot found anything about concepts. Why isn't it included in std?

Comment: what is a "string like object"? Does it have `append`? Or `insert`? Does it support construction from `std::string`? Does it have `size`? Does it have `length`? Or `data`? What use do you see for such a concept and how would that be any better than using `const std::string&` or `std::string_view`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was looking for a concept for a function, which accepts only const char*, char* and strings

```
template<class T>
concept StringLike = std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>;
```

did the trick for me :)

Comment: If you're just going to convert it to a `string_view`, why not just take a `std::string_view` type? What's the point of the concept, if the *only operation* you're going to do with it is to make a `string_view` out of it?

Comment: @NicolBolas i was writing a python format (std::format is not implemented yet) analog with varaidic templates, so i wanted arguments that are convertible to string or can be passed to std::to_string. That said my format function can be used as `my_format("{0}", std::string("1"))`, `my_format("{0}", "1")` or `my_format("{0}", 1)`

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Who says he's taking the string as an argument? Maybe he meant to do compile time dispatching based on the type using this concept.

Comment: @glades: Because the questions says, "I was looking for a concept **for a function**".

Answer (score 1):

Based on

> `/* is same as const char*, char*, std::string etc */`

the answer is *no, there's nothing the same as `const char*`, `char*`, `std::string`*, because they are different types. Well, `const char*` is just a non-modifiable `char*`, but `std::string` is a totally different thing. And nothing can be the same as `std::string` and `char*` at the same time, just like no integer number can be both equal and not equal to 0.

Comment: I think you are picking too much on the "and", I think OP is just looking for `const char*` *or* `char*` *or*  `std::string`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, based on the title of the question, I think the OP refers to something interchangeable with those three. Like a concept expressing a common interface. Not sure, however. Let's see his feedback.

Comment: @Enlico std::is_convertible_to_v<T, std::string_view> did the trick :)

Comment: @SherAndrei, probably you meant `std::is_convertible_v`. You can self-answer, then.