# Template that overloads operator<< to print string-like items in quotes

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'm trying to add some friendlier debug printing for stl containers. Ideally I'd like a single template that can print any stl container and enclose anything that's a string or string-like in quotes. I want something that works on c++17 and up.

Problem 1: How to define "any stl container"?
I'm hoping for either anything with a begin and end iterator, or anything that you can use in a range based for loop. I definitely want it to support initializer lists. I'm willing to constrain that further if necessary. Tuples would be really nice, but I don't think it's sane to combine them with homogenous containers.

Problem 2: How to define "string or string-like"?
Specifically `const char*`, `std::string`, and `std::string_view`. I'm probably missing some others. I don't really care about wide character support but it would be nice.

Problem 3: How to print a pointer?
I don't really care if it's the default (address on most platforms) or something that could dereference the pointer. It's probably simpler to just go with the default and I'm happy with that.

Example

```cpp
vector vec = vector("first", "second one", "third and final");
cout << vec;
// should print "[ \"first\", \"second one\", \"third and final\" ]"
vector other_vec = vector(1,2,3);
cout << other_vec;
// should print "[ 1, 2, 3 ]"
```

This is the code I have so far. It only works for vectors and I haven't figured out how to detect strings to enclose them in quotes.

```cpp
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename TItem>
auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, std::vector<TItem> v) {
  os << "[ ";
  for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
    if (it != v.begin()) {
      os << ", ";
    }
    os << *it;
  }
  os << " ]";
  return os;
}
```

I tried adding this as well, to specialize the template, but I get an error that "Function template partial specialization is not allowed clang(function_template_partial_spec)"

```cpp
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& operator<< <TChar, TTraits, std::string>(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, std::vector<std::string> v) {
  os << "[ ";
  for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
    if (it != v.begin()) {
      os << ", ";
    }
    os << "\"" << *it << "\"";
  }
  os << " ]";
  return os;
}
```

EDIT: This mostly works. If I replace `std::vector<TContainer>` with just `const TContainer&` I get build errors see below.

```cpp
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename TItem>
auto& print(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, TItem item) {
  os << item;
  return os;
}

template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& print(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const std::basic_string_view<TChar, TTraits>& item) {
  os << "\"" << item << "\"";
  return os;
}

template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& print(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits>& item) {
  os << "\"" << item << "\"";
  return os;
}

template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& print(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const TChar* item) {
  os << "\"" << item << "\"";
  return os;
}

template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename TContainer>
auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, std::vector<TContainer> container) {
  os << "[ ";
  for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
    if (it != container.begin()) {
      os << ", ";
    }
    print(os, *it);
  }
  os << " ]";
  return os;
}
```

It looks like something in gtest is breaking the generic container approach. Yes I'm using gtest to test my testing framework. I haven't gotten around to make it self testing yet. On the plus side this only affects testing my test framework. It should still work for most things.

```bash
In file included from tinytest_test.cpp:9:
./tinytest.h:77:27: error: member reference type 'const testing::internal::MutexBase *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
  for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
                 ~~~~~~~~~^
                          ->
external/com_google_googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1717:60: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator<<<char, std::char_traits<char>, const testing::internal::MutexBase *>' requested here
        << "The current thread is not holding the mutex @" << this;
                                                           ^
In file included from tinytest_test.cpp:9:
./tinytest.h:77:28: error: no member named 'begin' in 'testing::internal::MutexBase'
  for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
                 ~~~~~~~~~ ^
./tinytest.h:77:52: error: member reference type 'const testing::internal::MutexBase *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
  for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
                                          ~~~~~~~~~^
                                                   ->
./tinytest.h:77:53: error: no member named 'end' in 'testing::internal::MutexBase'
  for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
                                          ~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

EDIT 2: It seems that other pointers were getting caught up in the print overload for (const TChar*). I first got around that by adding a specialization for (const void*) and later just removed all of the operator<< overloads. Now I just have a handful of PrettyPrint functions that handle containers, quoted types, and everything else separately.

For anyone who's curious this is what I ended up with. I haven't tested the wide versions much yet. Too much stuff in my testing framework still only supports narrow chars.

Thanks for the help.

```cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Helper templates - These are not directly tested.
template <typename TChar>
struct StringTraits;

template <>
struct StringTraits<char> {
  static constexpr const char* Literal(const char* narrow, const wchar_t* wide) { return narrow; }
};

template <>
struct StringTraits<wchar_t> {
  static constexpr const wchar_t* Literal(const char* narrow, const wchar_t* wide) { return wide; }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Forward Declarations

// const char* and const wchar_t*
template <typename TChar>
std::basic_string<TChar> EscapeForPrinting(const TChar* text);

// std::string and std::wstring
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> EscapeForPrinting(const std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits>& text);

// std::string_view and std::wstring_view
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> EscapeForPrinting(const std::basic_string_view<TChar, TTraits>& text);

// const char* and const wchar_t*
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const TChar* item);

// std::string and std::wstring
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits>& item);

// std::string_view and std::wstring_view
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const std::basic_string_view<TChar, TTraits>& item);

// std::tuple
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename... TArgs>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const std::tuple<TArgs...>& tuple);

// Containers (anything with a begin and end iterator)
template <typename TChar,
          typename TTraits,
          typename TContainer,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<TContainer>().begin()), decltype(std::declval<TContainer>().end())>>,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<
              std::input_iterator_tag,
              typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::declval<TContainer>().begin())>::iterator_category>>>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, TContainer container);

// Catch-all for everything else. Just print it and hope that works.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename TItem>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, TItem item);

// Prints varargs with a const char* or const wchar_t* separator between each pair.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename... Args>
auto& PrettyPrintWithSeparator(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits> os, const TChar* separator, Args&&... args);

// Prints varargs with a std::string or std::wstring separator.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename... TArgs>
auto& PrettyPrintWithSeparator(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits> os,
                               std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> separator,
                               TArgs&&... args);

// Prints varargs with a std::string_view or std::wstring_view separator.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename... TArgs>
auto& PrettyPrintWithSeparator(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits> os,
                               std::basic_string_view<TChar, TTraits> separator,
                               TArgs&&... args);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Actual implementations

// const char*
template <typename TChar>
std::basic_string<TChar> EscapeForPrinting(const TChar* text) {
  std::regex regex = std::regex(StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\033", L"\033"));
  const TChar* replace = StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\\033", L"\\033");
  return std::regex_replace(text, regex, replace);
}

// std::string
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> EscapeForPrinting(const std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits>& text) {
  std::regex regex = std::regex(StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\033", L"\033"));
  std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> replace = StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\\033", L"\\033");
  return std::regex_replace(text, regex, replace);
}

// std::string_view
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> EscapeForPrinting(const std::basic_string_view<TChar, TTraits>& text) {
  std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> text_as_string = std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits>(text);
  std::regex regex = std::regex(StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\033", L"\033"));
  std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> replace = StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\\033", L"\\033");
  return std::regex_replace(text_as_string, regex, replace);
}

// const char*.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const TChar* item) {
  os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\"", L"\"") << EscapeForPrinting(item)
     << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\"", L"\"");
  return os;
}

// std::string.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits>& item) {
  os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\"", L"\"") << EscapeForPrinting(item)
     << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\"", L"\"");
  return os;
}

// std::string_view.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const std::basic_string_view<TChar, TTraits>& item) {
  os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\"", L"\"") << EscapeForPrinting(item)
     << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("\"", L"\"");
  return os;
}

// std::tuple
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename... TArgs>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, const std::tuple<TArgs...>& tuple) {
  std::apply(
      [&os](auto&&... args) {
        if (sizeof...(TArgs) == 0) {
          os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("[]", L"[]]");
          return;
        }
        size_t n = 0;
        os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("[ ", L"[ ");
        ((PrettyPrint(os, args) << (++n != sizeof...(TArgs) ? StringTraits<TChar>::Literal(", ", L", ")
                                                            : StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("", L""))),
         ...);
        os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal(" ]", L" ]");
      },
      tuple);
  return os;
}

// Containers
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename TContainer, typename, typename>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, TContainer container) {
  os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal("[ ", L"[ ");
  for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) {
    if (it != container.begin()) {
      os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal(", ", L", ");
    }
    PrettyPrint(os, *it);
  }
  os << StringTraits<TChar>::Literal(" ]", L" ]");
  return os;
}

// Catch-all for everything else.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename TItem>
auto& PrettyPrint(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& os, TItem item) {
  os << item;
  return os;
}

// Prints args with separator between them. const char* separator.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename... Args>
auto& PrettyPrintWithSeparator(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits> os, const TChar* separator, Args&&... args) {
  ((os << args << EscapeForPrinting(separator)), ...);
  return os;
}

// Prints args with separator between them. std::string separator.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename... TArgs>
auto& PrettyPrintWithSeparator(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits> os,
                               std::basic_string<TChar, TTraits> separator,
                               TArgs&&... args) {
  (((PrettyPrint(os, args), os), EscapeForPrinting(separator)), ...);
  return os;
}

// Prints args with separator between them. std::string_view separator.
template <typename TChar, typename TTraits, typename... TArgs>
auto& PrettyPrintWithSeparator(std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits> os,
                               std::basic_string_view<TChar, TTraits> separator,
                               TArgs&&... args) {
  (((PrettyPrint(os, args), os), EscapeForPrinting(separator)), ...);
  return os;
}
```

Comment: Break `os << *it;` line out into a separate template function. Overload it for `std::string_view` parameter to print it differently.

Comment: Replace `typename TItem` with `typename Container`, and `std::vector<TItem> v` with `const Container& v`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried that and unfortunately the compiler is trying to use this to print everything, not just things with begin and end methods. The error seems specific to gtest, but I'm not really sure why I'm matching with that type yet.

Comment: @majinnaibu You are not restricting your `operator<<` via SFINAE/concept to just types that implement `begin()`/`end()` methods. You should use `std::begin(container)` instead of `container.begin()`, and the same for `end()`, then you don't have to worry about that as the standard library has already done this work for you. Also, your `operator<<` and non-quoting `print()` need to take their inputs by const reference, not by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem 1: How to define "any stl container"?

Simply change your template so that the template argument of the container is the complete container type and not just the value type of `std::vector` specifically. And then use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` for the iterators, as they are already overloaded for any container type that supports iterators.

> Problem 2: How to define "string or string-like"?

You can use `if constexpr` with `std::iterator_traits::value_type` to look for types that `std::quoted` can support, eg:

```
// based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812868/65863
template<typename T>
struct is_quotable : std::disjunction<
                       std::is_same<char *, std::decay_t<T>>,
                       std::is_same<const char *, std::decay_t<T>>,
                       std::is_same<wchar_t *, std::decay_t<T>>,
                       std::is_same<const wchar_t *, std::decay_t<T>>,
                       std::is_same<std::string, std::decay_t<T>>,
                       std::is_same<std::wstring, std::decay_t<T>>,
                       std::is_same<std::string_view, std::decay_t<T>>,
                       std::is_same<std::wstring_view, std::decay_t<T>>
                     >
{
};

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_quotable_v = is_quotable<T>::value;

template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename Container>
auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, const Container &c) {
  os << CharT('[') << CharT(' ');
  for (auto it = std::begin(c); it != std::end(c); ++it) {
    if (it != std::begin(c)) {
      os << CharT(',') << CharT(' ');
    }
    if constexpr (is_quotable_v<typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(it)>::value_type)
      os << std::quoted(*it);
    else
      os << *it;
  }
  os << CharT(' ') << CharT(']');
  return os;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Pj7JNx--c)

> Problem 3: How to print a pointer?

`operator<<` already handles that for you. Once you account for `char*`, `wchar_t*`, etc in the `quoted` branch, any other pointer should invoke the standard `void*` overload of `operator<<` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and thorough answer. is_quotable is really cool. Unfortunately I'm getting build errors when replacing `std::vector<TItem>` with `const TContainer&`. Is this going to pickup any type that doesn't already have an operator<<? I might need to go the template metamagic route to fence this off to just things with begin and end methods that return an iterator.

Comment: @majinnaibu I expanded my demo to show this code works for other kinds of containers besides just vectors, including C-style arrays which don't have `begin()`/`end()` methods. [New Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Pj7JNx--c)